# Shortcode outputting at top of content

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode that is always outputting at the top of the page content. I am not sure on the correct usage for the output buffer in this instance.

Below is my shortcode function:

```
function nt_course_note_call_sca() {

    // only show logged-in members on learn dash pages
    $post_type  = get_post_type();
    $types      = apply_filters( 'learndash_notes_supported_types', array( 'sfwd-courses', 'sfwd-topic', 'sfwd-assignment', 'sfwd-lessons' ) );

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){

        if( in_array( $post_type, $types ) ) {

          return nt_course_note_entry_field();

        }

    }

}

add_shortcode('reflective_learning', 'nt_course_note_call_sca');
```

Output of nt_course_note_entry_field

```
//Prints Note field in front end and retieves exisintg note as placeholder
function nt_course_note_entry_field() {

    global $post;

    //ID's
    $current_user       = get_current_user_id();
    $current_lesson_id  = $post->ID;
    $current_post_type  = get_post_type();

    //Checks if note exists and changes title and body variables accordingly
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'coursenote',
        'post_status'   =>  array( 'draft', 'publish' ),
        'meta_query'     => array(
            //'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'nt-note-current-lessson-id',
                'value'   => $current_lesson_id,
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        ),
         'author' => $current_user
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($the_query->have_posts()){

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

            //$title    = get_the_title();
            $body   = get_the_content();

            //var_dump( $body );

        endwhile;

     wp_reset_postdata();

    } else {

        //$title    = __( 'Note Title', 'sfwd-lms' );
        $body   = __( '', 'sfwd-lms' );

    } 


    // get the course title or custom field if it exisists

if( get_field('reflective_learning_question', $current_lesson_id) ) {

    $title  = get_field('reflective_learning_question', $current_lesson_id);



    } else {
$title  = get_the_title($current_lesson_id);
        //$title    = __( 'Note Title', 'sfwd-lms' );
        //$body     = __( '', 'sfwd-lms' );

    } 





    ?>

  <div id="nt_note_cont" class="note-container">



    <div class="nt-note-wrapper">

        <div class="note-header">

          <div class="note-header-title">
            <span class="nt-close-icon">x</span>
            <?php _e( 'Reflective Learning', 'sfwd-lms' ); ?>
          </div>

          <div class="note-header-actions"></div>

        </div> <!--/note-header-->

        <div id="apf-response"></div>

        <div class="note-body">

          <form id="nt-course-note" action="" method="post">

                <?php wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__), 'nt-course-note-nonce') ?>
                <input type="text" name="nt-note-title hide-me" id="nt-note-title" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" placeholder="" >

                <p name="nt-note-title" id="nt-note-title-display"><?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?></p>


                <input type="hidden" name="nt-note-user-id" id="nt-note-user-id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_user ); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="nt-note-current-lesson-id" id="nt-note-current-lessson-id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_lesson_id ); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="nt-note-current-post-type" id="nt-note-current-post-type" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_post_type ); ?>">

                <textarea type="text" name="nt-note-body-custom" id="nt-note-body-custom" value="<?php echo $body; ?>" placeholder="" ><?php echo $body; ?></textarea>


                <?php

                $args = array(
                    'media_buttons'     =>      false,
                    'textarea_name'     =>      'nt-note-body',
                    'editor_height'     =>      175,
                    'quicktags'         =>      false,
                    'teeny'             =>      true,
                );

                add_filter( 'teeny_mce_buttons', 'nt_tiny_mce_buttons', 10, 2);
                wp_editor( $body, 'nt-note-body', $args );
                remove_filter( 'teeny_mce_buttons', 'nt_tiny_mce_buttons' ); ?>

                <br>

                <input type="text" id="xyz" name="<?php echo apply_filters( 'honeypot_name', 'date-submitted') ?>" value="" style="display:none">

                <ul id="nt-note-actions">
                    <li><a href="#" class="learndash-notes-print-modal" data-note="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><i class="nticon-print"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="learndash-notes-download-modal" data-note="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><i class="nticon-file-word"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

                <input type="submit" id="nt-note-submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save', 'sfwd-lms' ); ?>"/>

                <p class="nt-reset-dimensions"></p>

          </form>

        </div> <!--/.note-body-->

    </div> <!--/.nt-note-wrapper-->

  </div>
   <?php
}
```

How am I able to prevent this outputting at the top of the page and output in the correct placement?

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you also include the code for `nt_course_note_entry_field`. I suspect the problem is in there and it is either using `echo` to output, or calling something else that does.

Comment: Added this into the original question

Comment: Given the way you're outputting the html in the inner function, it would take a lot of work to fix. You'd need to put all the html in a string variable and return it instead of echoing it. I'd suggest the only viable solution is the one proposed in the answer by @majick

Comment: The method that @majick proposed, does that just replace the  `return nt_course_note_entry_field();` ?

Comment: I changed the first block of code in my question to the below but it still outputs at the top?

`// Calls Notes if Template Pages
function nt_course_note_call() {

 // only show logged-in members on learn dash pages
 $post_type  = get_post_type();
 $types   = apply_filters( 'learndash_notes_supported_types', array( 'sfwd-courses',  'sfwd-topic', 'sfwd-assignment' ) );

 if ( is_user_logged_in() ){

  if( in_array( $post_type, $types ) ) {

    ob_start();
 nt_course_note_entry_field();
 $result = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 return $result;
  }

 }

}`

Comment: Yes, that should work. I haven't tried it. But it looks right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when there is echoed output from the shortcode rather than the result being returned...

I'd wager `nt_course_note_entry_field` likely echoes rather than returns. If there is one - or you can create one) - use a similar function like `nt_get_course_note_entry_field` that does not echo.

If you can't change the function you can wrap it in an output buffer and return the result that way, eg.

```
 ob_start();
 nt_course_note_entry_field();
 $result = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 return $result;
```